# Conexion a BD Node js SQL Server

Tags: sql, nodejs, web, mssql

alguien me podría ayudar con esto?
Tengo una aplicación que se conecta a SQL Server mediante MSSQL , cuando me conecto vía localhost si muestra los datos, pero si me conecto desde otra PC no muestra nada.
Alguien sabe que está mal?
Saludos.

Esta es mi conexion  a BD.

````
    user: 'sa',
    password: 'pass',
    server: '192.168.1.17',
    database: 'database',
    port: 1433,
    pool: {
        max: 10,
        min: 0,
        idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
      },
    options: {
        encrypt: false, // for azure
        enableArithAbort: true,
        trustServerCertificate: false // change to true for local dev / self-signed certs
    }
};

async function getConnection() {
    try {
        const pool = await sql.connect(dbSettings);
        console.log("Conctado a BD")
        return pool;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

}```

[![Esto es cuando me intento conectar desde otra maquina][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lol1M.png

[![Esto es cuando esta localhost][2]][2]

  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzjlC.png
````

Comment: Dónde está corriendo tu servidor? En una computadora personal?

Comment: Qué dice la pestaña "network" del navegador? en node, tienes algún servicio para logs? Estás en una red de máquinas virtuales? Estás en una red local? están las computadoras en redes distintas? cuáles son tus configuraciones del firewall? Cuál es tu configuración de **port forwarding**? **Puede tu pc hacerle ping a la otra pc?**

Comment: *no muestra nada. Alguien sabe que está mal?*... Literal, pueden ser miles de razones

Comment: Creo que tu solocion seria montar el servicio que tienes corriendo en `192.168.1.17` a un `server-cloud`, puedes probar con [Gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/) o [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/es).